# In epidemiology, how to perform direct standardization when demographics don't exist in some populations?

Tags: missing-data, epidemiology

Suppose you have data on cancer incidence for different demographics in US counties. Direct standardization is a way of accounting for demographic differences between counties. If $r_i$ is the cancer rate for demographic $i$ in a given county, and $N_i$ is the population count of demographic $i$ in the entire US, then a "directly standardized rate" can be calculated as 
\begin{align*}
\sum_i r_i N_i.
\end{align*}
What are the options for dealing with counties that have no population in certain demographics? The two alternatives I can think of are adjoining demographics until every county observes every demographic-specific rate, which would throw out a lot of information, or treating those rates as missing data, which seems like it would require many unverifiable assumptions. Does direct standardization break down at this point, or are there other approaches?

Comment: @usεr11852 Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear. I have the population counts for each demographic in each county. My problem is that some population counts are zero (eg small counties with no minorities) and therefore the directly standardized rate isn't mathematically defined (since no county-level demographic-specific rate is observed).

Comment: Oops! I misread this! Probably I need to go to sleep! :)